# using ctrl+w inputs in blazemeter jmeter RTE plugin

Tags: java, terminal, jmeter, terminal-emulator

I am in need of using some special key combinations for inputs in remote terminal like `ctrl+w`, `ctrl+t`, which is more like using some control key based key combinations to be used in emulated terminal. However, the current blazemeter plugin does not allow these keys or combinations.

Since, I am using the plugin, i am exploring the code base, in case there is a different Remote terminal emulator for jmeter that allows us to use `ctrl+w` like key combinations or if there are some changes that can be made to accept these inputs, it will be of very great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the solution and want to add it to upstream the [plugin is open source and lives at Github](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin) and you can create a [pull request](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin/pulls)

Just in case, have you tried the latest [RTE Plugin 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-RTE-Plugin-3.0) (or later), it comes with recording functionality so it might be a chance you will be able to record and replay your key sequences.

Comment: we are using the version `3.2.0` which does not allow the usage of `ctrl+w` like key combinations. so waiting for some help or once we are implementing, might update here

Comment: The latest version of the plugin as of now is 3.1.0, I have no idea what you're using

Comment: there was a confusion, we are using 3.1.0. There is no support for passing the keys like `ctrl+w` to the remote server, do you have any idea how to enable the support to pass control and other key to the remote terminal.